# Compress PDF file to a selected size

Tags: pdf, compression

I have a 60mb PDF file I need to reduce it to 10 mb.
I was wondering if there are any tool to do it.

Comment: Why do you assume it's even possible?  Most parts of the file can't be reduced, period.  Only images can be reduced and you'll have to give up a lot of image quality to do that if it's even possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a file is a measure of the information stored in that file.

Some sorts of information can be compressed without compromising the overall benefit or purpose of the information, some cannot. Some compressible information types can be compressed significantly while still retaining its basic purpose, some can only be compressed slightly.

Further, some means of storing information have different properties in relation to the above principles.

To summarize: your proposed goal is exceptionally likely to be approaching impossible. Or, no, you cannot.